# How to make Browser Window draggable?

Tags: electron

I have a Browser Window (using Electron.atom.io) and I'm trying to make it so that you can click over most of the screen (except inputs, etc) and drag it over your desktop - basically, I don't want to restrict drag just to the title bar.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Electron supports a webkit property intended for frameless windows, that I believe should work for you. The documentation is [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#set-custom-draggable-region). Basically just make a class and add it to any elements you want draggable:

```
.draggable {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Also, as an added note for others, I'm disabling the selection of text in some areas, so it works a little more like a native app. (e.g. Dashlane for an example)

Comment: Note: `-webkit-app-region: drag` is known to have problems while the developer tools are open, so if it's not working, remember to close the developer tools.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore

Comment: Link is updated.